# My parity node constantly gets requests from 0x0

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes

I ran my parity node (stable version) with this command on a docker:

`/bin/parity 
--chain=kovan \
--jsonrpc-interface all \
--jsonrpc-hosts all \
--light \
--force-sealing \
--auto-update=all \
--min-gas-price 1000000000 \
--gas-floor-target 8000000 \
--jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,traces,rpc,personal \
rpc=trace \
--jsonrpc-cors=all`

It is working fine, although I keep getting these requests all the time from author 0x0. Can anyone explain why are these requests taking place?

[image]